# googlepay_button_content missing stripe

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, google-pay, flutter-stripe

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
   > Android resource linking failed
     ERROR:/Users/mac/Downloads/test/build/stripe_android/intermediates/packaged_res/debug/layout/plain_googlepay_button.xml:10: AAPT: error: resource drawable/googlepay_button_content (aka com.mycompany.test:drawable/googlepay_button_content) not found.
```

i changed the subscription packages from test to live mode and changed the keys accordingly and encountered this issue, i kinda know the error that xml files are missing but idk how to fix it